# Windows update is blocked on our servers. How can we change this?

Tags: windows, networking, security, update

We have a small office network. Internet connection works fine and all computers can connect to all websites apart from the microsoft site. How can i undo this so i can update my computer?

I am a computer novice with no knowledge of networking so simple language please. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What error do you see when accessing the windows update site?

Comment: What versions of Windows are you running?  Do you have any servers?

Comment: also this could be a sign of virus.

Answer (score 1):

Before making any attempts to change something, contact your network administrator and ask him the same question.

The most likely reason you cannot update your Windows machine, is because your user account there does not have the required privileges to do so. In order to perform updates on Windows, you must be logged in with the Administrator account -or an account that is part of the Administrators group.

If the access to Windows Update services is actually blocked on network level by the network administration personnel, I'm sure there might be a good reasons for that. You see, the maintenance of systems is their job -I am sure you wouldn't like if someone interfered with your job and made a mess out of it. Neither would they.

On the other hand, there is a good chance that something like this can be caused by malware infection. Try scanning your systems with antivirus software. Also, you could take a look at your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) file, and check if Windows Update hostnames are mapped for example to localhost, or some other IP addresses other than the actual Windows Update servers.